# postgresql select row with minimum value

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

This is my query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT 
    "axapta_calls".id, 
    "axapta_calls".call_time, 
    calls.calltime, 
    "calls"."id" as "call_id",  
    abs(extract(epoch from (axapta_calls.call_time::timestamp - calls.calltime::timestamp))) as ab 
FROM 
    "axapta_calls" 
inner join 
    "calls" (ON 
        axapta_calls.converted_outer_phone=calls.caller_phone
        and abs(extract(epoch from (axapta_calls.call_time::timestamp - calls.calltime::timestamp)))<= 600 )
WHERE  ("axapta_calls"."id" > 0) 
GROUP BY "axapta_calls"."id", "calls"."id"
```

And result is:

[image]

How to get only one row with minimum "ab" value?

I change this query to:

```
SELECT 
    distinct on (axapta_calls.id)
    "axapta_calls".id, 
    "axapta_calls".call_time, 
    calls.calltime, 
    "calls"."id" as "call_id",  
    abs(extract(epoch from (axapta_calls.call_time::timestamp - calls.calltime::timestamp))) as ab 
FROM 
    "axapta_calls" 
inner join 
    "calls" ON 
        axapta_calls.converted_outer_phone=calls.caller_phone
        and abs(extract(epoch from (axapta_calls.call_time::timestamp - calls.calltime::timestamp)))<= 600 
WHERE  ("axapta_calls"."id" > 0) 
GROUP BY "axapta_calls"."id", "calls"."id"
```

But get second row with ab = 347.783. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please tag correctly. Postgres isn't MySQL and isn't Oracle.

Comment: @ Sloan Thrasher, maybe there will be people, who khow the answer

Comment: They are too different in features and syntax.

Comment: @SloanThrasher `DISTINCT ON` has to be Postgres...but maybe the OP wanted a solution for any database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an `ORDER BY` clause.  You should be ordering first by the `id`, then by the `ab` column.  Then, Postgres will return a single record for each `id` corresponding to the lowest `ab` value.

```
SELECT 
    distinct on (axapta_calls.id),
    "axapta_calls".id, 
    "axapta_calls".call_time, 
    calls.calltime, 
    "calls"."id" as "call_id",  
    abs(extract(epoch from (axapta_calls.call_time::timestamp - calls.calltime::timestamp))) as ab 
FROM 
    "axapta_calls" 
inner join "calls"
    ON axapta_calls.converted_outer_phone=calls.caller_phone and
       abs(extract(epoch from (axapta_calls.call_time::timestamp - calls.calltime::timestamp)))<= 600 )
WHERE  ("axapta_calls"."id" > 0)
ORDER BY
    axapta_calls.id, 5;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save my day!

Comment: @Baurzhan Reload the page, I updated my answer.  You need to `ORDER BY id, ab`, if you want to use `DISTINCT ON (id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytics function as well:

```
select *
from 
(SELECT 
    "axapta_calls".id, 
    "axapta_calls".call_time, 
    calls.calltime, 
    "calls"."id" as "call_id",  
    abs(extract(epoch from (axapta_calls.call_time::timestamp - calls.calltime::timestamp))) as ab,
    rank() OVER (ORDER BY ab )rnk
FROM 
    "axapta_calls" 
inner join 
    "calls" (ON 
        axapta_calls.converted_outer_phone=calls.caller_phone
        and abs(extract(epoch from (axapta_calls.call_time::timestamp - calls.calltime::timestamp)))<= 600 )
WHERE  ("axapta_calls"."id" > 0) )
where rnk=1
```